# What is the best way of parsing and replacing text within HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing an extension for a gaming website. The game is recorded in text form and posted on forums. My extension will parse the page looking for a block of text it recognizes as a game, and replace it with a div that will display the game they wrote down.

The issue I have encountered is that the site puts p tags and other bits of HTML in the middle of the game text I'm trying to parse. The parser cannot handle random bits of HTML of course.

I can retrieve the game text without the HTML by using document.body.innerText instead of innerHTML, but I can't figure out how I'm supposed to replace it with the HTML result of my parser. If I were using HTML in and HTML out it would be as simple as document.body.innerHTML.replace(oldHTML, parsedHTML), but I'm using the stripped text to start with.

How can I solve this problem in the most eloquent way possible? Am I thinking about this wrong?

Edit to clarify:

Here is how it appears as it is now:

```
[GAME] some text blah blah blah <p> blah </p> blah blah blah [/GAME]
```

when I use innerText, I can get what I need which is:

```
[GAME] some text blah blah blah blah blah blah blah [/GAME]
```

I can parse this, but how do I insert my result over the original HTML? I can't replace it with the HTML-stripped text, because it will not match

Comment: Did you try `elem.innerHTML = elem.textContent`?

Comment: Would start by looking for a highligter library or plugin that already does this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to delete this, but I think I figured it out right after I posted it of course. I can just save the original HTML as a variable, copy it, strip the HTML from it, parse it, and replace the original variable with the parsed result.